# Mootools Request.HTML returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I am loading Mootools dynamically in the scripting part of an app (AutoWWW) because it does not allow direct HTML usage.

I am using Request.HTML and want to get the html of a page but it returns an 'undefined' message. How can i fix this?

My code:

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}

var mootools = new Request({
    url: 'http://google.com',
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(responseText){
        alert(responseText);
    }
});

loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools.min.js", mootools);
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, can you explain better? To me it looks like you are trying to load the MooTools library with MooTools methods before its even loaded, from the MooTools website which is not a CDN.

Comment: I just edited my post and changed the request url as it was confusing and i had set it to the homepage just to test. Basically i want to return the HTML of a url like google.com with GET and display it in an alert. The loadScript function is not mootools, the function should work and load mootools.min.js then call the mootools callback function which runs the GET request using the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you should take into account. One is possible CORS limitations, the other is that when you do `head.appendChild(script);` it will load the script asynchronously.

This means MooTools will be loaded but it will not be available until the `callback` function is called. To fix this you should have the callback internally inside the `loadScript` function, and from inside that callback call the other callback that was passed as function argument.

```js
function loadScript(url, callback) {
  // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';

  script.onreadystatechange = callback;
  script.onload = function() {
    new Request({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
      method: 'get',
      onSuccess: callback
    }).send();
  };
  script.src = url;

  head.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools.min.js", function(text) {
  alert(text);
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works, just wondering what would be the best practice to run more mootools functions other than the json request? For example if i wanted to call a function to POST also, the way the functions are packed inside one another and the callbacks are kinda confusing.

Comment: @zeddex inside the callback you pass to the loadScript function you can add MooTools code, there MooTools is added to the page. So replace the alert in the example with MooTools code.